# updating asp.net grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp.net grid view.

I call some sql-server stored procedure and

attach it to the gridView:

```
                    gvResults.DataSource = dr;
                    gvResults.DataBind();
```

I want to make a specific column editable.

How do i attach the update sp to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UpdateCommand

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Comment: Did that, but the boolean field (in the editable column) didn't turn to editable checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Try a handler for Rowdatabound for the gridview:

```
      protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{       
    try
    {
        HyperLink hlControl = new HyperLink();
        hlControl.Text = "Info";
        hlControl.NavigateUrl = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
        e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(hlControl);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

I wrote this to change the response from datasource in specific column to be changed to hyperlink control, you can do anything you want with the column.